# how to get texture in webgl?without Canvas.toDataUrl()

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I want to get texture from webgl just like i can use `getImageData()`when the canvas context is 2d.
how can i get texture form webgl context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know three possibilities. Important! [For all these methods you must set preserveDrawingBuffer = true with webgl](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.2).

**To data url**

[First one is high level method toDataURL and its origin is javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

```
canvas.toDataURL(type, encoderOptions);
```

You can use this for example if you want to allow your client to do some app "screenshot"

[Following two methods are low level and its origin is webgl.](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/) You can use them if you want to for example modify texture or calculate new texture (shadows).

**5.14.12 Reading back pixels**

Pixels in the current framebuffer can be read back into an ArrayBufferView object.

`void readPixels(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, ArrayBufferView? pixels)`

**5.14.8 Texture objects**

Texture objects provide storage and state for texturing operations ...

`void texImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLenum internalformat, GLint border, GLenum format, GLenum type, HTMLCanvasElement element)`